# paso de variable boton php

Tags: php, formularios, entrada

os cuento mi problema: quiero borrar una publicacion presionando el boton "Eliminar". El caso es que quiero pasar el id del boton (que es el titulo de la publicacion) a otro archivo php mediante un form con post. El codigo del formulario es el siguiente:

```
// retrieve selected results from database and display them on page
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM publicaciones WHERE id_usuario='.$id.' LIMIT ' . $this_page_first_result . ',' . $results_per_page;
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {?>
    <div class="eliminar-anuncio"> <?php

    echo '<span id="titulo-inmobiliaria">' . $row['titulo'] . '</span><br><span id="fecha">Publicado el ' . $row['fecha_publicacion'] . '</span>';
    ?>

    <form action="componentes/misAnuncios/borrarAnuncio.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" id=<?php echo "'" . $row['titulo'] . "'"; ?> name="borrar_anuncio" value="Eliminar anuncio">
    </form>

    </div>

    <?php


}

?>
```

y de aqui, al presionar el boton pasar a este archivo donde se tiene que borrar la publicacion

```
<?php

include_once('../../config/dbh.inc.php');

if (isset($_POST['borrar_anuncio'])) {
        $titulo_borrar = $_GET['titulo'];
        echo $titulo_borrar;

        $sql_borrar = "DELETE FROM publicaciones where titulo = '".$titulo_borrar."'";

        mysqli_query($conexion, $sql_borrar);
        mysqli_close($conexion);

        //header('Location: index.php?option=misanuncios');

}

?>
```

lo he intentado con un $_GET como podeis comprobar pero no hay manera. ¿Alguien sabria como hacer esta funcionalidad? Muchas gracias de antemano, un saludo!

Comment: Aparte de lo que te recomienda @Juan en su respuesta, yo usaría Ajax para esto, enviando vía Ajax el id del registro que va a ser eliminado. En cuanto a PHP, usaría consultas preparadas, pasar una variable directamente en una instrucción SQL para ser ejecutada es altamente peligroso, podrías sufrir serios ataques de inyección SQL cuyos daños son impredecibles.

Answer (score 2):

En el `<input>` el `id` se utiliza en el html y css, el parámetro que viaja al servidor cuando haces submit es lo que está en el atributo `value`.

En la forma en que estás enviando los datos, necesitas agregar un segundo `<input>` con el id del registro a eliminar, para que no se vea lo puedes hacer `type="hidden"`.

Por otro lado, en el formulario estás usando `method = "POST"`, entonces para leer los parametros tienes que usar `$_POST[]`, `$_GET[]` va a estar vacío.

```
<form action="componentes/misAnuncios/borrarAnuncio.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo "'" . $row['titulo'] . "'"; ?> " name="titulo" value="<?php echo "'" . $row['titulo'] . "'"; ?> "/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="borrar_anuncio" value="Eliminar anuncio">
</form>
```

Y en el archivo `componentes/misAnuncios/borrarAnuncio.php`:

```
$titulo_borrar = $_POST['titulo'];
```

Adicionalmente el campo `titulo` no es un buen candidato para usar como id en el html.
Normalmente los títulos de las publicaciones tienen espacios y en html5 los ids no deben tener espacios. Mi sugerencia es que en lugar del campo titulo uses un id numérico único que dependiendo de tu modelo de datos puede ser o la clave primaria de la tabla (si está armada de esta forma) o un campo que podes agregar como `unique` y `not null`. Y luego armas el id como `publicacion_<n>`, donde `<n>` es el valor de ese campo. Ejemplos: `publicacion_1`, `publicacion_2`, etc.